# a general definition of the volume of a high dimensional polytope

Tags: integration, algebraic-geometry, polyhedra

I would like to find a general definition of the volume for a full dimensional polytope in $R^n$. Could anyone  give me a hint please!

Thank a lot

Comment: Do you really mean definition or a way to compute it from some representation? If it's the latter what representation do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is the same as for any measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it's the [Lebesgue measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) of polytope's interior. More elementary definition can use the [multiple Riemann integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral#Mathematical_definition) of the polytope's chracteristic function instead, that would correspond to approximating the polytope by small boxes and taking the limit. In dimensions higher than two it is not generally possible to split an arbitrary polytope into simplices (like a polygon can be split into triangles) to get a definition without limits, but it is possible for generic [convex polytopes](http://www.cs.elte.hu/~karolyi/polieder.pdf), see also [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1991-57-195/S0025-5718-1991-1079024-2/S0025-5718-1991-1079024-2.pdf).

For ways to compute the volume see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/979/algorithm-for-finding-the-volume-of-a-convex-polytope.) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135714/calculating-volume-of-convex-polytopes-generated-by-inequalities) related questions.

Comment: Thank you very much, i just want to know an official definition. However, i did not find any document talking about it.