# Is it possible to integrate volumes for high dimension polyhedra

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

If it is possible how does one, integrate to find the volume of a polyhedrado?

Answer (score 2):

The definition is the same as for any measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it's the [Lebesgue measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) of polytope's interior. More elementary definition can use the [multiple Riemann integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral#Mathematical_definition) of the polytope's chracteristic function instead, that would correspond to approximating the polytope by small boxes and taking the limit. In dimensions higher than two it is not generally possible to split an arbitrary polytope into simplices (like a polygon can be split into triangles) to get a definition without limits, but it is possible for generic [convex polytopes](http://www.cs.elte.hu/~karolyi/polieder.pdf), see also [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1991-57-195/S0025-5718-1991-1079024-2/S0025-5718-1991-1079024-2.pdf).

For ways to compute the volume see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/979/algorithm-for-finding-the-volume-of-a-convex-polytope.) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135714/calculating-volume-of-convex-polytopes-generated-by-inequalities) related questions.