# Probability question on uniform distribution

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

I need help with the following question:

> A computer in adding numbers rounds each number to its nearest integer.
>   Suppose that all rounding errors are independent and uniformly distributed over (-0.5, 0.5).
>
> i) If 1500 numbers are added, what is the probability that magnitude of the total error exceeds 15?
>
> ii) How many numbers may be added together so that magnitude of the total error is less than 10 with probability 0.9?

How I started:

Let **X** be a random variable denoting the rounding error.

Probability distribution function $f(x)$ of $X$ would be:

$1 \quad -0.5 \le X \le 0.5$

$0 \quad otherwise$

I can't figure out how to answer the first part. Someone please help.

Comment: You are supposed to know the central limit theorem: the sum of iid variables with finite variance tends to a gaussian. Then, compute the mean and variance of that gaussian (it depends on the mean and variance of the variable that is summed, here an uniform)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know central limited theorem is required for this. Still if you post a solution I'll be grateful :-)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution You may use this distribution of $\sum (U_i\sim(0,1))$ and shift $x$ by linear transformation as $U_i\sim(-0.5,0.5)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has been answered here: [Connection to Normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31365/connection-to-normal-distribution)

Using Thomas Ahle's formula there gives the exact answer.
\begin{align*}
  P(S<s) = \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor s\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(s-k)^n
\end{align*}

We need to compute: $$\big(1-P(S<765)\big)\cdot 2 \approx 0.17972990949058$$

Using the normal approximation:

\begin{align*}
  2\times \mathbb{P}\left(x>15\right) &= 2\times \mathbb{P}\left(z>\frac{15}{\sqrt{125}}\right) \\
  &= 2\times \int_{15/\sqrt{125}}^{\infty} \, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\, \pi}} e^{-z^2/2}\, dz \\
  &\approx 0.17971249
\end{align*}

or use the table for normal distribution.